# I can't download new Plasma widgets and Plasma themes in Kubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: kubuntu, 16.04, kde, plasma, widgets

Each time I try to download the new Plasma widget from the Plasma Add-On Installer, I get the following error:

```
Loading of providers from file: http://download.kde.org/ocs/providers.xml failed
```

**Screenshot:** [image: Screenshot of Plasma Add-On Installer]

The same problem is also happening when I am trying to install new theme. Please check the below screenshot for clarification:

[image: Screenshot of KDE Control Module Add-On Installer]

Any suggestions, comments or answers will always be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: do you have a proxy between your computer and the internet?
does your internet work as expected?

Comment: If you go to download.kde.org in your browser, you can see that there is no ocs subdirectory. That means that it's looking in the wrong place. I don't know how to fix that or what to change it to, though.

Comment: @syss : I don't have any proxy running.

Comment: @Ben : Yes, you are right! This link should be changed to something else but i don't know either where to find the providers.xml file or how to change it. Thank you for pointing that out though.

Answer (score 0):

I found about 20 files in /etc/xdg/ that all reference

```
ProvidersUrl=http://download.kde.org/ocs/providers.xml
```

I think the download.kde server currently sends a redirect to

```
https://autoconfig.kde.org/ocs/providers.xml
```

But I guess its not followed.

Comment: Please help OP with some fix as well

Answer (score 0):

I think this python code will help you out..

```
import os

os.chdir("/etc/xdg")
file_list=os.listdir("/etc/xdg")

home=os.getenv("HOME")

os.mkdir(home+'/.kde/share/apps/providers')

provider="""<providers>
<provider>
<id>api.kde-look.org</id>
<location>https://api.kde-look.org/ocs/v1/</location>
<name>api.kde-look.org</name>
<termsofuse>https://api.kde-look.org/content/terms</termsofuse>
<register>https://api.kde-look.org/register</register>
<services>
<person ocsversion="1.6"/>
<content ocsversion="1.6"/>
</services>
</provider>
</providers>"""

prov=open(home+'/.kde/share/apps/providers/providers.xml', 'w')
prov.write(provider)
prov.close()

s_add="ProvidersUrl="+home+"/.kde/share/apps/providers.xml\n"

for i in range(len(file_list)):
    try:
    with open(file_list[i]) as t:

        new=""""""

        x=1
        for line in t:
            if "ProvidersUrl=http://download.kde.org/ocs/providers.xml" in line:
                new=new+s_add
                print file_list[i] + "====> is changed"

            else:
                new=new+line


    t.close()
    with open(file_list[i],'w') as f:
        f.write(new)

    f.close()
except IOError:
    pass
```

And sorry if my code is bad!..Just did my best!!

Answer (score 0):

For me this worked:

```
cd /etc/xdg
khotnewstuff4 plasmoids.knsrc
```

I adapted this from here https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/kde-runtime/+bug/1610665.
The bug is also discussed here http://defrances.co/post/kdelook/.

Answer (score -1):

Type https://autoconfig.kde.org/ocs/providers.xml in browser.

Copy contents.

Create a providers.xml file and paste them into it.

Go to /etc/xdg/

Change this line

```
ProvidersUrl=http://download.kde.org/ocs/providers.xml
```

to

```
ProvidersUrl=file:///path/to/your/custom/xml/file/providers.xml
```

in all the files that have it.

I'm sure there is a single terminal command you can use to do that in all files, but I don't know what that is. Maybe someone can improve this answer. I suggest changing it on a single file first and testing the corresponding app first. The file that corresponds to the plasma add-on installer mentioned should have a pretty obviously fitting name.

I found the info in this guide and followed it myself for a different error:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/kde-runtime/+bug/1610665

I'm not sure why just changing the line to

```
ProvidersUrl=https://autoconfig.kde.org/ocs/providers.xml
```

wouldn't work. I can't test that, because I don't have the question's error.

Or why the guide uses a local path url that doesn't seem to work on my end...I posted here what worked for me.